# Print an individual email that is part of a conversation

Tags: macos, mail.app, printing

Mail.app Version 8.2 (2104), OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.  I have a message in my inbox which I would like to print, but Mail associates it with a conversation in another mailbox and the print preview shows the entire conversation.  How do I print just the message in my inbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail *does* only print the selected email in a conversation rather than the entire conversation.

The problem is that the selected email at the end of an email chain includes a quoted copy of the previous emails. This can't be removed as it is part of the email that you selected. If you only want the text that the author of the email wrote, you will need to copy the content out into a text document and print that instead.

Comment: Right, I was assuming it would print as it appeared on screen.  Too bad that isn't even an option.